# How to type check this object without using {} or any?

Tags: typescript

I got an object like this:

```
const state = {
      isFormOK: true,
      fieldA: {
          value: 'abc';
          status: 'ok' | 'normal' | 'error';
          errorText: '';
      }
}
```

There could be many fields which has the same pattern like the above `fieldA` property, and in the code, I will actually use index property to access them because they are random. So I declared a type like this:

```
export interface FieldState {
  value: string;
  status: 'ok' | 'normal' | 'error';
  errorText: string;
}

export interface ComponentState {
  isFormOK: boolean;
  [fieldName: string]: FieldState
}
```

If you just swap those `interface` with `type`, then it works for `flow.js`. Whereas can't do that in Typescript, because as the doc said:

> While string index signatures are a powerful way to describe the “dictionary” pattern, they also enforce that all properties match their return type. This is because a string index declares that obj.property is also available as obj["property"].

And the error is:

> Property `isFormOK` of type `boolean` is not assignable to string index type `FieldState`

I think it's fine, because when I access the state using an index, I might go to the case where the index equals `isFormOK` but I still want to use it like a `FieldState`. I know. But how could I solve it and type check this object?

I tried modified that `[fieldName: string]: FieldState` to `[fieldName: string]: FieldState | boolean`. Then this interface declaration pass, but later on in the code, `state[randomFieldName].value` will have error like: `Property value doesn't exist on type boolean | FieldState`.

Tried changing `[fieldName: string]: FieldState` to `[fieldName: string]: {}`, then cast it to `FieldState` everytime when use it. it works. But then the type for `state` doesn't convey the message where the real pattern of this object.

So How do I type checking this `state` object including both `isFormOK` and `fieldA` without using `{}` or `any`?

Comment: Try using type alias and intersection instead: `type ComponentState = { isFormOk: boolean } & { [field: string]: FieldState }`

Comment: @Aaron Thanks, solved my problem! Could you add it as an answer?

Comment: Be warned that even though such a type can be read from it isn't so easy to assign to (at least not without type assertions). The problem is `isFormOk` becomes equivalent to `boolean & FieldState` which does not really exist.  If that's okay with you, great.  Otherwise there may be other solutions.

Comment: @jcalz Actually, that doesn't seem to be the case, or at least that's not how it behaves, but I am not actually sure why. `state.isFormOk` only has type `boolean`. I think it has something to do with how property types are resolved within intersections of index types...

Comment: The line `const x: ComponentState = {isFormOk: true}` results in an error (at least for me) that complains about `true` not being assignable to `FieldState`.

Comment: @jcalz Ah, good catch, it seems when assigning an object literal it expects `isFormOk` to be `boolean & FieldState` which is not usable. Odd that `state.isFormOk` only has `boolean` (so there are workarounds) but it's a definite gotcha.

Comment: @jcalz It's not optimal. But seems the best we could get for the current version. I posted an issue in their repo, Seems already a similar proposal there, but with a complex syntax... https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23927

Answer (score 0):

It works with type aliases and intersection types:

```
type FieldState = {
  value: string;
  status: 'ok' | 'normal' | 'error';
  errorText: string;
}

type ComponentState = { isFormOK: boolean; } & { [fieldName: string]: FieldState };

declare const state: ComponentState;

state.isFormOK = true // (property) isFormOK: boolean
state.foobar.value // (property) value: string
state["foobar"].status // (property) status: "ok" | "normal" | "error"
```

[Example in Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20FieldState%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20value%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20status%3A%20'ok'%20%7C%20'normal'%20%7C%20'error'%3B%0D%0A%20%20errorText%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ComponentState%20%3D%20%7B%20isFormOK%3A%20boolean%3B%20%7D%20%26%20%7B%20%5BfieldName%3A%20string%5D%3A%20FieldState%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20state%3A%20ComponentState%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Astate.isFormOK%20%3D%20true%0D%0Astate.foobar.value%0D%0Astate.foobar.status%0D%0Astate.foobar.errorText)

### Edit: Object literal assignment issue:

As **@jcalz** pointed out there seems to be a problem with assigning an object literal to this type, specifically `isFormOK` is expected to have the type `boolean & FieldState` (even though property access `state.isFormOK` resolves to just `boolean`), and that's an unusable type that will result in an error when you try to assign to it:

```
const state: ComponentState = { isFormOK: true, fieldA: { value: "foo", status: "ok", errorText: "err" } }
```

> ```
> Property 'isFormOK' is incompatible with index signature.
>   Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'FieldState'.
> ```

If you are ok with making `isFormOK` optional, or starting with a `Partial<ComponentState>`, you can assign the `isFormOk` afterwards:

```
type ComponentState = { isFormOK?: boolean } & { [fieldName: string]: FieldState };
const state: ComponentState = { fieldA: { value: "foo", status: "ok", errorText: "err" } }
state.isFormOK = true;
```

An issue about this is currently open on Github: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867

### Edit 2: Mapped types

Per the issue linked above, TS considers it a bad idea to have an indexer that doesn't match all the properties, even though Flow allows it, because of errors like this:

```
let key: string = "isFormOK"
state[key] // FieldState because key is string, but at runtime its a boolean
```

One possible workaround if you know the expected field names is to use [mapped types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) instead of an index type:

```
type ComponentState<F extends string> = { isFormOK: boolean; } & { [P in F]: FieldState };

const state: ComponentState<"fieldA"> = {
  isFormOK: true,
  fieldA: {
    value: "foo",
    status: "ok",
    errorText: "err"
  }
}
```

If you know the field names ahead of time this is probably better, because it will guard against trying to reference a field that doesn't exist (like `state.fieldZ` above).

You can derive the keys from values if you have them somewhere else, for example:

```
function submitFields<K extends string>(fields: { [P in K]: any }): ComponentState<K> {
  // ...
} 

const state = submitFields({ fieldA: "foo", fieldB: "bar" })
state.isFormOK
state.fieldA.status
state.fieldB.status
```

If you *don't* know the field names ahead of time (for example a generic form builder tool) then this won't get you all the way. (*Edit* jcalz seems to be one step ahead with a generic type that can work with dynamic field names, check it out!)

Comment: I think this is fine, because in my case, the `isFormOK` and `fieldA` will be set in a different places rather than set them all in one object literal. But yeah, seems we need more support from the compiler level. Really thanks, gonna wait for a while to see if there are more discussion.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript doesn't currently have a way to express the idea of "all possible keys except for the following specific ones".  If TypeScript had real [subtraction types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4183) you might be able to refer to a type like `string - "isFormOK"` and use it to build up the type you want.  But this is currently not possible directly.

The intersection type proposed by @Aaron might be acceptable but has caveats as mentioned above, and kind of relies on the type checker not really being thorough in some instances.  If that works for you, great.  Otherwise, read on:

---

Another possibility is to work around the lack of general subtraction types by  using [literal subtraction types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12215), which do exist in TypeScript.  Instead of saying "all possible keys except for the following", you say "all keys *from this specific list* except for the following".  The idea in this case is to make `ComponentType` generic and dependent on some set of property keys:

```
type ComponentState<K extends keyof any> = 
  { [P in K | "isFormOK"]: P extends "isFormOK" ? boolean : FieldState }
```

(This uses [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) introduced in TypeScript 2.8, but you can get something similar with pre-2.8 syntax if you need it.)  In the above, you're saying that `ComponentState<K>` is dependent on some set of keys `K`, and that for every value in `K` the property type is `FieldState` unless the value is `"isFormOK"`, in which case the type is `boolean`.

This generic type is a bit more cumbersome to work with than a plain type, but here's how you might do it.  The following code only accepts inputs that are assignable to some `ComponentState<K>`, and returns the same type:

```
function asComponentState<C extends ComponentState<keyof C>>(componentState: C): C {
    return componentState;
}
```

The constraint `C extends ComponentState<keyof C>` forces the type checker to examine the keys of whatever you pass in as type `C`, and use those as the specific list of keys suitable for literal type subtraction.  Let's see if it works:

```
const state = asComponentState({
    isFormOK: true,
    fieldA: {
        value: 'abc',
        status: 'ok',
        errorText: ''
    },
}); // okay, ComponentState<"isFormOK" | "fieldA">

const missingKey = asComponentState({
  fieldA: {
    value: 'abc',
    status: 'ok',
    errorText: ''
  }
}); // error, Property 'isFormOK' is missing

const wrongFieldState = asComponentState({
  isFormOK: true,
  fieldA: {
    value: 'abc',
    status: 'ok',
    errorText: ''
  },
  fieldB: "whoops"
}); // error, 'fieldB' is incompatible, 'string' is not 'FieldState'.
```

Looks good to me!

Again: the upside is the type checker is enforcing exactly the constraint you want.  The downside is that every reference to `ComponentState` needs to be generic.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Really thanks for this answer. Got some deeper understanding on Typescript types...So for your ComponentState, seems I can't put it in a function parameter? Because It needs an extra parameter `C` to start?

Comment: You can put it in a function parameter, as long as you also introduce the proper generic type parameter to the function.  That's what `asComponentState()` is doing.  Is there something specific you're wondering how to do?

Comment: The `asComponentState` approach doesn't seem to work if you replace `FieldState` with a function type and then pass an object literal containing methods (arrow functions work, though).

Comment: I reported the above issue here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29520