# Is it possible to have mixed specific typed keys in a TypeScript type, and a generic key type?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I'm trying to create a type to describe an ES6 Proxy object where I will know the types for a few keys, and the rest of the keys will be generic with a callback as a value and I won't know their names until runtime.

However, if I try something like this:

```
interface MyCallback {
  (): void;
}

interface MyType {
    myKey1: number;
    [key: string]: MyCallBack;
}
```

I get errors like:

```
[ts] Property 'myKey1' of type 'number' is not assignable to string index type 'MyCallback'.
```

If I add `[key: string]: number`, I get the error `Duplicate string index signature`.

If I overload it so it's like `number | MyCallback`, I get this error if I try to call a callback on a `MyType` instance:

```
[ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'number | MyCallback' has no compatible call signatures.
```

Is it possible to have a type like I'm trying to create in TypeScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to type check this object without using {} or any?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50198477/how-to-type-check-this-object-without-using-or-any)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is sort of. You can accomplish this with intersection types:

```
interface MyType {
    myKey1: number;
}

interface MyCallBack {
    (): void;
}

interface GenericCallbackType {
    [key: string]: MyCallBack;
}

type CombinedType = MyType & GenericCallbackType;

const obj: CombinedType = {
    myKey1: 8,
    anyString: () => {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works for me if I make it an intersection type, like `type CombinedType = MyType & GenericCallbackType;` instead.

Comment: whoops, actually meant to put intersection, my bad, good catch!

Comment: Is a specific setting required for this? I get the following on 2.8.3: `Property 'myKey1' is incompatible with index signature. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'MyCallBack'.`

Comment: @empyrical, would either you care to comment on your TS version? Docs and [typescript issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867) say that this should not work (and it doesn't in 2.8.3).

Comment: I'm using version 2.6.2 - I haven't tried other versions yet, but VS Code hasn't been giving me any complaints yet. I notice one of the commenters mentions issues with assignments, but I am just accessing and have no need for assignment in my use case.

Comment: not working for me also. is this answer still valid?

Comment: In typescript 4.2.4 you'll get `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'MyCallBack'.ts(2322)`.

Answer (score 3):

the accepted answer didn't work for me, this snippet works: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aq6AOKDeAUMicgLboDSE6AjAFzIgCuZARtANyEC+hhoSLEQoA4hBDRgCAMJwANvLaIA1tjzIipZAG0VNRgGcwUUAHMAuowAUASmQBeAHzIAbgHtgAE259CYXBQZd3ZQCC91FAc0LEDkAB9kcUlTWQUlVUjuQgR3EGNkdzYAK0Zg0MkIuOitUgpqOkYADgAaYlI4EHQAZRNzG3tnTT4eIA)

```js
interface MyType {
    myKey1: number;
}

interface GenericCallbackType {
    [key: string]: () => void;
}

type CombinedType = MyType | GenericCallbackType;

const obj: CombinedType = {
    myKey1: 8,
    anyString: () => {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments the accepted answer doesn't work with assignments, resulting in a `Property 'myKey1' is incompatible with index signature` error. To work with assignments we can utilize [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49982981/1763012):

```js
interface MyCallback {
  (): void
}

interface MyType {
  myKey1: number
}

const asCombinedType = <C>(
  res: C & MyType & Record<Exclude<keyof C, keyof MyType>, MyCallback>
): C => res

const obj = asCombinedType({
  anyKey: () => { /* ...*/ },
  myKey1: 12
})
```

Admittedly a bit convoluted but it gets the job done.